# How to install a fork from github as a dependency?

Tags: npm

I've made a fork of some repository and I need to use that fork as a dependency for my project.

Right now I do:

```
 npm install angular --save
```

How do I change this to install a fork?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [NPM documentation for the install command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> `npm install <git remote url>`
>
> Installs the package from the hosted git provider, cloning it with git. First it tries via the https (git with github) and if that fails, via ssh.