# TypeScript: import { X } from 'Y' - how to substitute/redirect Y

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I have an external library Y which is installed using `npm` and loaded from `node_modules`. It resides on GitHub. This is how I'm using it:

`import { X } from 'Y';`

I did a fork of Y and checked-out to a local folder/local git repository.

Now, I would like to use this local source code instead of an npm package. I dont want to modify my `imports`. Is there a way how to do that? I'm using TypeScript and angular-cli.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a fork from github as a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931706/how-to-install-a-fork-from-github-as-a-dependency)

Comment: Given that you just want to change the origin of the same dependency, all you have to do is update your project to use your fork. See also the documentation on [dependencies in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `npm link` - https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

It is a perfect and simple solution, no need to use `file:` references.